# How can i create session variables in Node.JS without express?

Tags: node.js, express, variables, session, cookies

I'm trying to build a CMS on Node.JS and this far i managed to build everything only by including MySQL module. I would like to continue building all the CMS core modules without the use of extern libraries like Express. I'm working now on the session for Login purposes. By now, i can create cookies with the header Set-Cookie where i store some information of the user to recognize its session when he/she loads all the pages in the site, but i still can't find some way to create session variables without the use of express or some other frameworks.

I'd be thankful if someone could give me some example.

Comment: Have you tried this [session management using core node.js without express.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932342/session-management-using-core-node-js-without-express-js)

Answer (score 4):

First off, unless you're building things yourself just because you want to learn how to do it all yourself, there's really no reason to re-invent things that have already been well engineered in existing modules.  Because this is server-side code, there's really no penalty for using an already tested module that does what you want.  So, my first recommendation would be to use Express and express-session.  It does all the session management for you and will give you lots more time to work on the aspects of your project that will really help it succeed or fail.

And, THE top benefit of using node.js in the first place is being able to use the huge library of existing code available through NPM and Github.

---

Conceptually, here's how a session works in the node.js/web browser client/server world.

1. Incoming request from client to web server.
2. Server creates some sort of guaranteed unique cookie value and sets that as a cookie on the response.
3. Server also creates a serve-side session object and puts that object into some data store with the session cookie value as an index into that data store.
4. Now every time a future request arrives from that same client, it will be accompanied with that session cookie.
5. On each incoming request, the server can grab the session cookie value, use it as the key to look up the corresponding session object and get it.
6. Any request handler can then read data from the session object or write data to the session object.
7. In this manner you can keep data associated with a particular client secure and safe on the server and usable from one request to another.

If you're going to implement your own session system, you have to be able to create these unique session cookies and create some sort of session storage (can be anything from a Map object in memory to a database), implement session expiration and session store cleanup and then provide appropriate middleware or utility functions that makes it easy to use on any individual http request.